# Zoo Visitor and Low Alphabet

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, low-alphabet, alphabetically

Is it possible to filter Low alphabet listings by member group with Zoo visitor?

Eg something like this:

```
{exp:low_alphabet:entries
    channel="members"
    alpha_ignore="the|a"
    numbers="after"
    group_numbers="yes"
    numbers_label="#"
    alpha_filter="{segment_3}"
    status="not closed" 
    orderby="title"
    show_group="7"
    sort="asc"
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
}
  {if count == 1}<h1>Company A-Z</h1>{/if}
  {if low_alphabet_heading}
    <h3>{low_alphabet_label}</h3>
    <ul>
  {/if}
      <li>
        <a href="{url_title_path="a-z/detail"}">{title}</a>
        <img src="employer_logo" alt="{title}"/>
      </li>
  {if low_alphabet_footer}
    </ul>
  {/if}
{/exp:low_alphabet:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Low Alphabet's [own parameters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet/docs/tags#entries), the Entries tag inherits all parameters from the [native channel:entries tag](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters). The `show_group` parameter is *not* present in either, so that won't do anything.

However, if I recall correctly, Zoo Visitor uses statuses to differentiate between member groups. That means you should be able to use the `status` parameter to target the member group you want to display.